# Python WatchedFileHandler keeps old log file descriptor after rotating the log in a Flask app run by UWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, log-rotation

I'm using the following Flask (2.0.1) app

```py
import logging
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, current_app
from logging.handlers import WatchedFileHandler


_LOG_PATH = "./test.log"

blueprint = Blueprint("dosomething", __name__)

@blueprint.route("/dosomething")
def dosomething():
    current_app.logger.info("do something")
    return "", 200

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.logger = logging.getLogger()
    app.logger.addHandler(WatchedFileHandler("./test.log"))
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    return app
```

run by UWSGI (2.0.20) server started like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ./env/bin/activate

./env/bin/uwsgi --http=0.0.0.0:8000 \
                --virtualenv=./env \
                --master \
                --mount /='app:create_app()'
```

I start sending HTTP requests like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while :
do
    curl 'http://localhost:8000/dosomething'
    sleep 0.5
done
```

After a few seconds I rotate the log file with:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mv test.log test_$(date -d "today" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").log
touch test.log
```

This is somewhat similar to what logrotate does without `copytruncate`.

The `WatchedFileHandler` immediately switches to the newly created file, however the old file's descriptor still stays there until the server gets restarted:

```bash
~/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi
$ sudo lsof -n | grep Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test
uwsgi     178885                   eugenesqr    9w      REG                8,4       624    4743480 /home/eugenesqr/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test_20230531174721.log
uwsgi     178891                   eugenesqr    6w      REG                8,4       169    4746295 /home/eugenesqr/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test.log
uwsgi     178892                   eugenesqr    9w      REG                8,4       624    4743480 /home/eugenesqr/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test_20230531174721.log

~/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi
$ ll /proc/178885/fd
...
l-wx------ 1 eugenesqr eugenesqr 64 May 31 17:47 9 -> /home/eugenesqr/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test_20230531174721.log
...
```

Even if `test_20230531174721.log` gets deleted, the space it occupied can't be used:

```bash
$ sudo lsof -n | grep Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test
uwsgi     178885                   eugenesqr    9w      REG                8,4       624    4743480 /home/eugenesqr/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test_20230531174721.log (deleted)
uwsgi     178891                   eugenesqr    6w      REG                8,4     10322    4746295 /home/eugenesqr/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test.log
uwsgi     178892                   eugenesqr    9w      REG                8,4       624    4743480 /home/eugenesqr/Downloads/watched_files_uwsgi/test_20230531174721.log (deleted)
```

This becomes a problem with bulky log files and apps, which run without restarts for long periods of time.

Some extra observations:

1. Logging in a simple python script without UWSGI and Flask works just fine: it immediately switches to a new file and the old file gets properly closed.
2. It's reliably reproducible with python3.6 and python3.10 even with the latest UWSGI 2.0.21 and Flask 2.3.2.
3. Removing `--master` from UWSGI start options "fixes" the problem.
4. UWSGI options like: `--touch-logreopen`, `--log-reopen`, `--vacuum`, `--max-requests=10` don't help.
5. Various soft-reload techniques like `echo r > /tmp/yourfifo` or

```bash
kill -HUP `cat /tmp/project-master.pid`
```

appear to be not soft enough, since some of my requests aren't get processed during the reload with errors like: `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

**The question**: is there a way to free the rotated file's descriptor without adding extra timer-based "cleanup" scripts?